# How to get the class reference from KParameter in kotlin?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

The code below is about reflection.
It tries to do 2 things:

1. `case1()` creates an instance from `SimpleStudent` class, it works.
2. `case2()` creates an instance from `Student` class, not work.

The reason that `case2()` not work as well as the question, is that inside that `generateValue()`:

1. I don't know how to check it is kotlin type or my own type(I have a dirty way to check `param.type.toString() not contain "kotlin"` but I wonder if there is a better solution
2. I don't know how to get its class reference when it's a custom class. The problem is that even though `param.type.toString() == "Lesson"`, when I tried to get `param.type::class`, it's `class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KTypeImpl`

So, how to solve it? Thanks

==============

```
import kotlin.reflect.KParameter
import kotlin.reflect.full.primaryConstructor
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

data class Lesson(val title:String, val length:Int)
data class Student(val name:String, val major:Lesson )
data class SimpleStudent(val name:String, val age:Int )

fun generateValue(param:KParameter, originalValue:Map<*,*>):Any? {
    var value = originalValue[param.name]

//    if (param.type is not Kotlin type){
//        // Get its ::class so that we could create the instance of it, here, I mean Lesson class?
//    }

    return value
}

fun case1(){
    val classDesc = SimpleStudent::class
    val constructor = classDesc.primaryConstructor!!

    val value = mapOf<Any,Any>(
            "name" to "Tom",
            "age" to 16
    )

    val params = constructor.parameters.associateBy (
        {it},
        {generateValue(it, value)}
    )

    val result:SimpleStudent = constructor.callBy(params)

    assertEquals("Tom", result.name)
    assertEquals(16, result.age)
}

fun case2(){
    val classDesc = Student::class
    val constructor = classDesc.primaryConstructor!!

    val value = mapOf<Any,Any>(
            "name" to "Tom",
            "major" to mapOf<Any,Any>(
                    "title" to "CS",
                    "length" to 16
            )
    )

    val params = constructor.parameters.associateBy (
        {it},
        {generateValue(it, value)}
    )

    val result:Student = constructor.callBy(params)

    assertEquals("Tom", result.name)
    assertEquals(Lesson::class, result.major::class)
    assertEquals("CS", result.major.title)
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    case1()
    case2()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved:

You could get that `::class` by using `param.type.classifier as KClass<T>` where `param is KParameter`

Comment: Can you please update the question with complete solution.

Comment: @SergioLeone I think my blog covers it well. http://www.albertgao.xyz/2017/10/02/kotlin-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-KParameter/

Comment: I saw that, thanks. I'm not having troubles with finding out if the class is custom or not. But I still can't solve the `argument type mismatch` error when the Student class is instantiated. So how do we actually solve creating an instance of a custom Lesson class from a map of params? Are you creating an instance of it inside the `if (type != null) {}` block? Can you show the updated generateValue() function? Thanks.